# Second structural equation on complex/holomorphic vector bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I'm going over Kobayashi's Differential Geometry of Complex Vector Bundles, and I see no mention of the famous second structural equation $$\Omega^i_j = d\omega^i_j + \sum_k \omega^i_k \wedge \omega^k_j,$$ where $\Omega = [\Omega^i_j]$ and $\omega=[\omega^i_j]$ are the connection and curvature matrices relative to a framed open set.

I'm begin to wonder, does this still hold in the case of a complex or holomorphic vector bundle? The proof of this requires only the Leibniz rule property of the connection so I don't see why it would not hold. I'm just curious since there is no mention about it on whether there is some nuance I'm missing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smooth complex vector bundles are just special instances of real vector bundles, so anything that applies to real vector bundles also applies to complex vector bundles.
For the second part, I'll assume you are talking about holomorphic connections on holomorphic vector bundles. Otherwise the first sentence of my post applies.

If an object is holomorphic, then there is also an underlying smooth object, to which you can apply any differential geometric operation. The question is: does this operation take you outside the holomorphic category?

In this case, the only actions that are involved are differentiating and wedging. The wedge of two holomorphic differential forms is holomorphic. The exterior derivative of a holomorphic differential $k$-form is
$$d\eta=(\partial+\bar{\partial})\eta = \partial\eta\in \Omega^{k+1,0}(M)$$
since $\bar{\partial}\eta=0$. So if $\nabla$ is a holomorphic connection on a holomorphic vector bundle with local holomorphic $1$-form $\omega$, the structure equation reads $\Omega=\partial\omega +\omega\wedge\omega$ and still holds true, and yields a holomorphic $2$-form.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: I mean certainly the statement “anything that holds in real vector bundles holds in holomorphic vector bundles” is false. I.e every real vector bundle admits a smooth metric, but it is not the case that any holomorphic vector bundles admits a holomorphic section

Comment: No, but every holomorphic vector bundle admits a smooth section. That is the point. You need to ask if the operation you are performing takes you outside the holomorphic category. And this one would, because you using a bump function to prove the existence of a global smooth section. @Chris

Comment: @QuaereVerum I agree, but I’d also say that means you should edit the first part of your answer to make that clear

Comment: I honestly don't see how I could make that more clear, but if you feel that it isn't, feel free to edit the answer in a way that you find clearer. @Chris